# Odd Button wrapping in Bootstrap 3 - Responsive Design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a Bootstrap 3 newbie so this may be as simple as a code structure problem. Everything looks great above 770px however there are a few things a bit broken below 770px. 1.) Search button will not float left. 2.) Select menus need to be 100% width. stacking menus is fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/nataliehatter/p55j2sp2/

HTML

```
<div class="well" style="padding:10px;">
                 <h5>Search Businesses</h5>
    <form class="form-inline">
    <label class="sr-only" for="selectLocation">Select Location</label>
    <select class="form-control searchSelect" id="selectLocation">
        <option selected="selected" value>Select Location</option>
        <optgroup label="U.S. Regions">
            <option value="R70">Atlantic</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="U.S. States">
            <option value="1">Alabama</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    <label class="sr-only" for="selectIndustry">Select Industry</label>
    <select class="form-control searchSelect" id="selectIndustry">
        <option selected="selected" value>Select Industry</option>
    </select>
    <label class="sr-only" for="selectIndustrySegment">Select Industry Segment</label>
    <select class="form-control searchSelect" id="selectIndustrySegment">
        <option selected="selected" value>Select Industry Segment</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success searchBusBtn">Search Businesses</button>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .form-control.searchSelect {
            width:25%;
            margin-right:5px;
        }
    .searchBusBtn {
        float:right;
    }
        @media screen (max-width: 768px;) {
            .form-control.searchSelect {
                width:auto;
            }
            .searchBusBtn {
                float:left;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your mediaquery from

```
@media screen (max-width: 768px;)
```

to

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px)
```

The following code in your CSS is what you need in your layout:
[**JsFiddle-Update 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/p55j2sp2/1/)

```
.form-control.searchSelect {
    width:25%;
    margin-right:5px;
}
.searchBusBtn {
    float:right;
}
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .form-control.searchSelect {
        width:100%;
        margin:5px 0 0 0;
    }
    .searchBusBtn {
        float:left;
        margin:10px 0 0 0;
    }
    .well {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not necessary to use @media rule or apply any float:right to the button class if you take those off, button will be placed in the right position when screen size changes, also in bootstrap if you want to float an element either to the right or left you can make use of classes like pull-right or pull-left you don't have to create a separate css file for that, i hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
@media screen (max-width: 768px) {
```

There was a wrong ";".